# how to query multiple months in where clauses in hql?

Tags: sql, hql

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE
    from_unixtime(end_time,'yyyyMMdd') >= '20211201'
and from_unixtime(start_time,'yyyyMMdd') <= '20211231'
```

I want to substitute '20211201' and '20211231' for every month between year 2020 to 2021, one way to do it is to substitute strings by hands and split it into multiple queries like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE
    from_unixtime(end_time,'yyyyMMdd') >= '20211201'
and from_unixtime(start_time,'yyyyMMdd') <= '20211231'
```

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE
    from_unixtime(end_time,'yyyyMMdd') >= '20211101'
and from_unixtime(start_time,'yyyyMMdd') <= '20211130'
```

Is there any way I can put them in one query? I'm thinking a **for loop** or **full join** a column with

```
month    
20211031
20221130
20211231
...
```

but I don‘t know a elegant way to generate a series of months between two dates either..

Comment: is it possible that **end_time** is before **start_time** ? I'm not sure how your data looks like but you may use a window funtion to partiton your table by each month between 2022 and 2021 and can make the reesult what you want.

Comment: end_time is strictly after start_time. I'm new to hql(sql), can you write a demo?plz

Comment: Any logic you're trying to do for every monthly data? want to aggregate the monthly data to calculate something like **SUM**, **MAX**, **AVG** for some columns ?

Comment: to count distinct user_id for MAU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
WITH table_name AS (
 SELECT 0 user_id, unix_timestamp('2022-01-02 12:00:00') start_time, unix_timestamp('2022-01-04 12:00:00') end_time  UNION ALL
 SELECT 1 user_id, unix_timestamp('2022-01-04 12:00:00') start_time, unix_timestamp('2022-01-08 12:00:00') end_time  UNION ALL
 SELECT 2 user_id, unix_timestamp('2022-02-02 12:00:00') start_time, unix_timestamp('2022-04-04 12:00:00') end_time  UNION ALL
 SELECT 3 user_id, unix_timestamp('2022-02-04 12:00:00') start_time, unix_timestamp('2022-02-08 12:00:00') end_time  UNION ALL
 SELECT 3 user_id, unix_timestamp('2022-02-02 12:00:00') start_time, unix_timestamp('2022-02-04 12:00:00') end_time UNION ALL
 SELECT 4 user_id, unix_timestamp('2022-04-02 12:00:00') start_time, unix_timestamp('2022-05-05 12:00:00') end_time
),
explodes AS (
  SELECT *, date_format(add_months(from_unixtime(t.start_time), diff), 'yyyyMM') month
    FROM table_name t
 LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE (
      -- this hack is due to lack of supporting *generate_array* functions and non-equi joins in Hive
      -- you can increase below map based on the period seen on your data
      map(0, array(0), 1, array(0, 1), 2, array(0, 1, 2), 3, array(0, 1, 2, 3), 4, array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4))[
          int(months_between(from_unixtime(t.end_time), from_unixtime(t.start_time)))
      ]) tf AS diff
)
SELECT month, COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) mau FROM explodes GROUP BY month;
```

##### previous approach with more limitations

Assuming that

1. your data is big enough not to miss any months between period you're considering.
2. you can set hive option below for non-equi join

> Cartesian products are disabled for safety reasons. If you know what you are doing, please sethive.strict.checks.cartesian.product to false and that hive.mapred.mode is not set to 'strict' to proceed.

```sql
WITH table_name AS (
  -- same as above
),
months AS (
  SELECT from_unixtime(start_time, 'yyyyMM') year_month FROM table_name
  UNION DISTINCT
  SELECT from_unixtime(end_time, 'yyyyMM') FROM table_name
)
SELECT m.year_month, COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) mau
  FROM months m LEFT JOIN table_name t ON m.year_month BETWEEN from_unixtime(t.start_date, 'yyyyMM') AND from_unixtime(t.end_date, 'yyyyMM')
 GROUP BY year_month;
```

Comment: sorry, my bad, start_time and end_time could be in different month.. but it has to be included in the targeting year-month.. for example '202101', the logic is in the sample code

Comment: In that case, the user will be counted as an active user for the month of **start_time**. note that I've commented out **where** clause.

Comment: but for example the start_time is '20210101' and the end_time is '20210401' then the user should be included as i count for 202101, 202102, 202103, 202104

Comment: I understood your needs thanks to your kind explanation. but afaik, hive doesn't support to generate an array dynamically, and lack of  non-equi join  above is my best try at the moment with some limitations